# iAd refusing to display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

iAd framework is doing my nut.  AGAIN!

Please someone help me towards sanity.

Yesterday was working on the simulator, today it isn't.   After an hour of raging at it I actually plug in my brain and log the error (iirc this is on the simulator)

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
>   UserInfo=0x5a5bb50 
>   {
>       ADInternalErrorCode=3,
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable
>   }

then I try a reboot.

on the simulator:

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Application has iAd Network configuration error"
>   UserInfo=0x5839510 
>   {
>       ADInternalErrorCode=4,
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application has iAd Network configuration error
>   }

now try on the device:

> Err Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 1.)"
>   UserInfo=0x19c8c0 {}

finally I find something on Google:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/11/28/ad-inventory-unavailable-with-ios-42.html

This guy is saying it seems to be an issue with >= iOS 4.2.

So I try again using iOS 4.0 iPhone simulator

Yay,  I get yet another error code.

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "Invalid data."

Comment: I'm having the same problems, was working yesterday just fine, but today it doesnt seem to work at all. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I seem to remember it was one of those problems that just went away after a while. Maybe the servers go down for maintenance...

Comment: Found any solutions? Facing the same problem ..

Comment: If my answer resolved your problem, I'd appreciate if you would accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

On your device, go to the Settings app. Tap Developer. Under iAd Developer App Testing, tap Fill Rate. Select the error rate you want to test.